# About sources of View.onScrollChanged()

Tags: java, android, view, android-source

Here are the sources of [`protected void View.onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java):

```
/**
 * This is called in response to an internal scroll in this view (i.e., the
 * view scrolled its own contents). This is typically as a result of
 * {@link #scrollBy(int, int)} or {@link #scrollTo(int, int)} having been
 * called.
 *
 * @param l Current horizontal scroll origin.
 * @param t Current vertical scroll origin.
 * @param oldl Previous horizontal scroll origin.
 * @param oldt Previous vertical scroll origin.
 */
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
    if (AccessibilityManager.getInstance(mContext).isEnabled()) {
        postSendViewScrolledAccessibilityEventCallback();
    }

    mBackgroundSizeChanged = true;

    final AttachInfo ai = mAttachInfo;
    if (ai != null) {
        ai.mViewScrollChanged = true;
    }
}
```

The question is about this line: `final AttachInfo ai = mAttachInfo;`. For what purposes `ai` was introduced and why it was made `final`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely, `mAttachInfo` is `volatile`; then the purpose of `ai` is to avoid `NullPOinterException` when two threads access this object and `mAttachInfo` is written after checking `mAttachInfo!=null` but before executing `mAttachInfo.mViewScrollChanged = true;`

Comment: `mAttachInfo` is declared in this way: `AttachInfo mAttachInfo;`, so it is not volatile... but it seems it should not be volatile for the described behavior...